# Converting Jupyter to PDF using Latax

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pdflatex, bibtex

I am trying to convert a Jupyter notebook to PDF using latex but i am facing the below issues. I believe it is to do with graphs that get generated when i compile my document. The file also contains references. Is there a way to fix this please? Many Thanks for everyone help!

```
Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater 
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 691.


! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in Machine_Learning_Project_2_f
iles/Machine_Learning_Project_2_36_1.png (no BoundingBox).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.719 ...iles/Machine_Learning_Project_2_36_1.png}

? Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, E to edit your file,
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
? Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, E to edit your file,
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
? Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, E to edit your file,
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
? Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, E to edit your file,
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.719 ...iles/Machine_Learning_Project_2_36_1.png}

Output written on Machine_Learning_Project_2.dvi (8 pages, 69388 bytes).
Transcript written on Machine_Learning_Project_2.log.
```

Comment: I know this isn't a real answer but a  very common way of converting notebooks is with nbconvert.  https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: Typically when you use includegraphics you add a width.

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{boat.jpg}
```

Please provide the line of code that is failing in latex, it is likely invalid latex code.

Comment: @GrandFleet I have updated the question to include the full error code. Thanks for your help. Where do i need to add ```\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{boat.jpg}```

Comment: Probably line 719?

Comment: @GrandFleet I am using python in Jupyter notebook. Can the above code be integrated to Python or do i need to use a separate cell and use r markdown.

Comment: what above code? Maybe markdown would be better

Comment: @GrandFleet I meant using the code in your comment to add to the Jupyter file. I have tried adding this code ```\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{bmpsize}``` in Jupyter but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling with latex (tex->dvi), but you should use, e.g., pdflatex as the graphics files are in PNG format.